# Is there any support for log probabilities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics, scipy

In numpy or scipy for Python, specifically Python 3, is there any support for expressing probabilities as log probabilities for various distributions? If so, where?

These are particularly important when probabilities are very small.  So, for instance, in `numpy.random.choice`, it is possible to specify a list of probabilities? For the case I'm seeking, it would be nice to specify (all of) these as log probabilities instead.

The comparable capability in R, for instance, is the parameter `log.p` which appears or has a counterpart in many of the statistical distributions. It means, in the specific case of the functions `qnorm` and `pnorm`, that, as a Boolean switch the probabilities should be returned as *logs of* the probabilities, not the probabilities themselves.

I would like, for example, instead of saying

```
s = numpy.random.binomial(100000, 0.0001, 1000)
```

to be able to say something like

```
s = np.random.binomial(100000, -9.2103, 1000, log_p=True)
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from just converting to non-logarithmic representation? Even if it underflows and your probability becomes 0, it's not going to affect the sample.

Answer (score 0):

**Scipy stats** has some that may suit your needs:

```
scipy.stats.lognorm
```

- log normal :http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html
- Other can be found there : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

[image]